# Is it possible to use Kubernetes for Gitlab build runners and how?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I want to set Kubernetes for CI runners on Gitlab. I want to use Kuberntes for continuous integration and build running, not deployment. Does somebody try that and how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [kubernetes executor](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/executors/kubernetes.md) for your gitlab runner

Comment: I tried that I set active runner but build is stuck. do you know ehat can be problem?

Comment: Stuck on what exactly?

Comment: If you are having difficulties and need help troubleshooting, please open another question and mark this one as resolved, this one has been answered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210620/kubernetes-executor-on-gitlab-error-job-failed-system-failure-post-api-v1