# Kubernetes executor gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Does anyone successfully setup kubernetes executor/runner on gitlab for CI jobs? I set up mine but its stucking on executing my pipeline indefinitely.

I'm running a runner as a docker container on top of kubernetes cluster and connecting to my gitlab instance for handling my CI builds.

Any working config file would be appreciated.

My runner configuration looks like  this:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "kube-executor"
  url = "https://gitlab.example.ltd/"
  token = "some-token"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.cache]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = "https://my-kubernetes-api-address:443"
    ca_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt"
    cert_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt"
    key_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.key"
    image = "docker:latest"
    namespace = "gitlab"
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = "ci-.*"
    privileged = true
    cpu_limit = "1"
    memory_limit = "1Gi"
    service_cpu_limit = "1"
    service_memory_limit = "1Gi"
    helper_cpu_limit = "500m"
    helper_memory_limit = "100Mi"
    poll_interval = 5
    poll_timeout = 3600
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
```

this throws this error: `ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Post https://my-kubernetes-api-address:443/api/v1/namespaces/gitlab/secrets: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: What is your config so far? Please be more specific with what you have done already and what the error is.

Comment: concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
[[runners]]
  name = "kubernetes"
  url = "https://gitlab.repo.ltd"
  token = "my-token-"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.cache]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = "https://my-kubernetes-api-address.ltd"
    --tls-cert-file = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt"
    --tls-private-key-file = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.key"
    --client-ca-file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt"
    image = "docker:latest"
    namespace = "ci"
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = "ci-.*"
    privileged = true
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]

Comment: this is the config I have in my /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

Comment: This is the error I'm getting back `ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Post https://"my-kubernetes-api-address.ltd/api/v1/namespaces/ci/secrets: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` @adebasi

Comment: Please edit your question and put those information there to improve readability.

Comment: @adebasi added the config as suggested

Comment: @Bubacarr Then your problem comes from certs, for me they were unnecessary, could you please try the config without the certs or do you really need them?

Comment: Yes, i need the certs as the runner is not part of my kubernetes cluster. I need to authenticate to the Kube API with a cert basically. Thats why I have them in my config. I believe, if the node is in the kubernetes, then i do not need the certs at that time.

Answer (score 0):

you are using https, so where are the certs, are they self signed certs? if yes you have to mention `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` flags in your configmap.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43362697/432115